# What is the simplest way to implement small group, low latency, one-to-many audio broadcast

Tags: audio, server, streaming, linode

I have a Linode server and need to broadcast one to-many audio (they can hear but can not talk back) to a group of three to five people. I looked at WebRTC and the Janus server but it seems complete overkill. Using commercial applications like Skype, Discord etc. results in low audio quality and it is mono. Best possible audio quality and low latency (on a par with that of Skype, Discord etc.) is essential.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend building such system based on Icecast streaming. It's an old proven technology which has a latency close to real-time.
You could use any set of Icecast-enabled tools for that.
As example, here's what you an do with tools by our company:

1. [Larix Broadcaster](https://softvelum.com/larix/) mobile app allows streaming in audio-only
   mode.
2. Nimble Streamer software media server can get Larix' input and
   [produce Icecast stream](https://wmspanel.com/nimble/audio_streaming). You can use any Icecast-enabled here
   instead.
3. [SLDP Player](https://softvelum.com/player/) can play Icecast produced by Nimble
   Streamer or any other Icecast-enabled server.

That can also be built with other companies products, so you can pick the right tools yourself.

Comment: Thank you Yury. I've looked at Shoutcast and Icecast but the latency would not be acceptable. I edited my question to specify what kind of latency I would need.

Comment: What are the measurements which you get with Icecast? And what software do you use for transmission and playback?

Comment: I didn’t try, but I read that shoutcast and icecast are not designed for close to real-time communication and have a few seconds of latency (btw I found my solution using cleanfeed.net).

Comment: You should definitely try Icecast yourself first, I'm not sure why it's described as high latency.

Answer (score 0):

A super simple setup would be to just use command line tool called ffmpeg (it also has an api) see doc at  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver

Where your source audio lives just launch either the ffmpeg or ffserver

```
ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf
```

in that config put location of source audio and output url it will publish to ... then your client receivers can use ffplay with

```
ffplay <stream URL>
```

ffmpeg is a free open source industry workhorse for audio/video manipulation ... its the underlying technology several more visable tools like [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) use under the covers

Comment: What kind of latency do you have with this method? I am looking for something with latency on a par with that of Skype, Discord etc. (I actually found my solution in the service offered at [Cleanfeed] (http://cleanfeed.net) but still interested on how this would be achieved).